# Campo do Banco bugando com valores de Milhar

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Galera, sei que é uma dúvida bem básica, mas como faço para um campo do meu Banco aceitar valores onde estes são valores como 1000+ e vindo também como decimais. Vou mostrar um exemplo a seguir no valor de: 3.084,05, a forma que este caiu no campo da BD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui como está a estrutura da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui o código PHP que faz a inserção do Banco:

```
<?php

<?php

// Submit do arquivo index.php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include 'conexao.php';

# Inclusão do Pedido
$id_pedido = $_POST['id_pedido'];
$id_fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor_id'];
$nome_fornecedor = $_POST['select_fornecedor'];
$nome_input_fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor_new_input'];
$cnpj = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("/", "", str_replace("-", "", $_POST['cnpj'])));
$valor_total = floatval(substr(str_replace("R$", "", str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['total_pedido'])),2));
$loja = $_POST['select_loja'];

echo $valor_total;
die();


if (isset($_POST['change_fornecedor'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (NULL, '{$id_fornecedor}', '{$nome_input_fornecedor}','{$cnpj}', NOW(), {$valor_total}, '{$loja}')";
    if (!$connect->query($sql) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção de pedido: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error);
    }
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (NULL, '{$id_fornecedor}', '{$nome_fornecedor}', '{$cnpj}', NOW(), {$valor_total}, '{$loja}')";
    if (!$connect->query($sql) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção de pedido: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error);
    }
}
```

Como solicitado, uma print pós mudança do código e da estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da maneira que está, testando com o valor 3.803,20 o `echo $valor_total` retorna o valor: 3.803

Answer (score 1):

No campo de valor vc tem que:

- Remover "R$"
- Remover "."
- Trocar "," por "."

  $valor_total = (float) str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(["R$", " ", "."], "", $_POST['total_pedido']));

**Você está utilizando uma função substr que está retornando parte do valor. E não tem necessidade nesse caso.

Realizei o teste abaixo:

```
$valor = "R$ 3.084,05";
$valor_total = (float) str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(["R$", " ", "."], "", $valor)); 
echo $valor_total;
```

Comment: Felipe, fiz a alteração e continuou vindo errado. Tenho que alterar a estrutura da BD tbm ?

Comment: Poderia postar como foi salvo no DB?

Comment: Troque de Float para Doble, assim poderá armazenar um valor maior.

Comment: Troquei para Double e ainda assim não funcionou. Vou editar a pergunta com a print nova.

Comment: **Double

Você realizou um dump da variável $valor_total? Posta pra mim

Comment: Adiconei o teste que eu realizei

Comment: Eu coloquei um var_dump no total do pedido e no preço total dos itens. O retorno foi este:

C:\wamp64\www\projeto_vale_vip\pedido.php:17:float 0
C:\wamp64\www\projeto_vale_vip\pedido.php:48:null

Comment: Com o seu teste ficou o seguinte:

C:\wamp64\www\projeto_vale_vip\pedido.php:17:float 0

C:\wamp64\www\projeto_vale_vip\pedido.php:48:null

3084.05

Comment: Pelo que entendi o problema está no seu código tente adaptar o meu teste no seu código.

Comment: Eu coloquei um die() no final do código para não rolar o INSERT e o seu teste ficou antes deste. Os valores que vêm do var_dump sempre são os mesmos, independente do valor do pedido / itens.

Comment: No meu teste troque esse: 
$valor = "R$ 3.084,05";

Por esse

$valor = $_POST['total_pedido'];

E poste o dump

Comment: Troquei e me retornou:

C:\wamp64\www\projeto_vale_vip\pedido.php:32:float 0



0

Comment: Parece que o valor de  $_POST['total_pedido'] está 0 faz um dump dele.

Comment: Se eu coloco um dump, ele nem aparece na tela.

Comment: Ele deveria aparecer, se não aparece fica complicado te ajudar!

Comment: Felipe, editei a pergunta mostrando o valor aparecendo agora. Com o código que você passou, ele realmente não aparece, mas deixando da maneira "original", está retornando o valor apenas sem os decimais. Mesmo assim, na BD ele não atinge nem este valor retornado.